# Where does the standard define the order of preference for binding of values to references?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, language-lawyer, value-categories

As it is explained [here](http://codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/07/24/const-rvalue-references/), values of different categories bind to references of different kinds according to the following order of preference:

```
struct s {};

void f (      s&);  // #1
void f (const s&);  // #2
void f (      s&&); // #3
void f (const s&&); // #4

const s g ();
s x;
const s cx;

f (s ()); // rvalue        #3, #4, #2
f (g ()); // const rvalue  #4, #2
f (x);    // lvalue        #1, #2
f (cx);   // const lvalue  #2
```

Where in the standard is this order of preference described?

Comment: This is called "overload resolution", see chapter [over]  (13 in the C++14 standard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[over.ics.rank]/3** 
>   - (3.1) Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence `S2` if
>
> ...
>
> (3.1.3) — `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings (8.5.3) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier, and `S1` binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and `S2` binds an lvalue reference.
>
> ...
>
> (3.1.6) — `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by `S2` refers is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by `S1` refers.

By these rules, a function taking rvalue reference is preferred over one taking lvalue reference, and then a function taking non-const reference is preferred over one taking const. Considering only overloads that are viable, of course.